# Have xargs pass a flag from stdin instead of command parameter

Tags: pipe, xargs

Given an application, `myApplication`, that streams lines to stdout

```
$ myApplication
flag1
flag2
flag3
```

**How do I use `xargs` to pass those values as flags to a command instead of passing them as parameters?**

For example, the resulting invocations should be:

```
anotherApplication --flag "flag1" parameterNotFromXargs
anotherApplication --flag "flag2" parameterNotFromXargs
anotherApplication --flag "flag3" parameterNotFromXargs
```

My failed attempt using the `-I` option produced the wrong output:

```
$ myApplication | xargs -L1 -I % echo "e: %"
e: %
e: %
e: %
```

Comment: What OS are you running? What version of `xargs`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unable to replicate:

```
$ echo -e "one\ntwo\nthree" | xargs -L1 -I% echo "I was told % times"
I was told one times
I was told two times
I was told three times
```

If `myApplication` is returning its output on standard input, the above invocation of `xargs` should work properly.  If the output you are seeing is actually standard error, you need to redirect that to standard output with `myApplication 2>&1`.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is a script

```
#!/bin/sh
anotherApplication --flag "$1" parameterNotFromXargs
```

And call it with

```
myApplication | xargs -L1 ./myscript.sh
```

If you want to avoid the script, you can use give the command inline:

```
myApplication | xargs -L1 sh -c 'anotherApplication --flag "$1" parameterNotFromXargs' _
```